# convert Kinect depth image to EmguCV image error

Tags: c#, kinect, emgucv

I just started to use EmguCV for Kinect image processing, and an ArgumentException occured when creating EmguCV image from depth stream like this:

```
    private void DepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        DepthImageFrame df = e.OpenDepthImageFrame();
        if (df != null)
        {
            short[] data = new short[df.PixelDataLength];
            df.CopyPixelDataTo(data);
            Bitmap b = data.ToBitMap(df.Width, df.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
            Image<Gray, short> im = new Image<Gray, short>(b); //run-time exception here
```

The ToBitmap extension method is entirely copied from the Kinect SDK tutorial example:

```
    public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this short[] data, int width, int height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat format)
    {
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, format);

        var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
            new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width,
            bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
            bitmap.PixelFormat);
        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, data.Length);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

I checked that `b` had an valid value, not null. I wonder why this exception occured, is it some image format problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
Image<Gray, byte> im = new Image<Gray, byte>(b);
```

Comment: I already found that `b` is invalid and when I change bitmap's format to rgb565 it worked, together with `<Gray, byte>`. But what should I do if I need to maintain the 16-bit precision? I heard that `bitmap` didn't really support the 16bit-gray-scale because there didn't exist 16bit graphic card, is it true? Now I'm trying to use `<Gray, short>` as a medium format and then copy the data to a `short[]` again, then directly convert the `short[]` to `BitmapSource`, I will test if this works. Thanks all the same